# Adding extended data to placemarks in python with pykml

Tags: python, kml, google-earth, pykml

I have uploaded some addresses to batchgeo along with several columns of data. I've downloaded the kml file which then has the coordiantes. The data structure is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>...</name>
            <description>....</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-3.1034345755337,57.144817425039,0</coordinates>
            </Point><address>...</address>
            <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

The "description" tag is a jumbled mess which has the extended data when you click on a point in Google Maps/Earth (url, address etc.). I now want to add some details underneath the current extended data. My current tack is to use [pykml](http://packages.python.org/pykml/tutorial.html#building-pykml-python-scripts), but I can't find an extended data attribute of a pykml object, and I don't see it listed in the documentation. When I click on a placemark in Google earth I want this to appear:

```
<Description>
item 1
item 2
item 3
</Description>
New data
```

Could you suggest how to achieve this? Thanks. (btw, [pylibkml](http://code.google.com/p/pylibkml/wiki/BasicTutorial) has this feature but it has been discontinued and I can't find a download link!)

Comment: I have the same question, but I'd like to use `CDATA` within the `<description>` tags... any ideas? Here is an example of how it looks like https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#descriptive_html

Comment: @eamon1234 I found a fork of [pylibkml](http://code.google.com/p/pylibkml/wiki/BasicTutorial) in github, just in case you want to use it: https://github.com/GRSEB9S/pylibkml

Answer (score 4):

Ok I will play a bit of necromancy here, and leave something which helped me to with similar problem. Here's what worked for me

```
pm = KML.Placemark(
                KML.name("My extended data point somewhere in sahara!"),
                KML.Point(KML.coordinates("10, 15")),
                KML.ExtendedData( 
                    KML.Data(KML.value('someValueGadzilion'),name='Your value name here')
                ) 
     )
```

Answer (score 3):

I've achieved what you say by using KML.description() method.

Code:

```
        placemark = KML.Placemark(
            KML.name('poi'),
            KML.description('blabla'),
            KML.LookAt(
                KML.longitude(lat),
                KML.latitude(lon),
                KML.altitude(alt),
                KML.heading('0'),
                KML.tilt(0),
                KML.range('0'),
            ),
            KML.Point(
                KML.coordinates(string)
            )
        )
```

Comment: do you know how to use with CDATA? thanks. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#descriptive_html